# Most efficient way to get subversion properties from server

Tags: svn

I want to get the svn:mime-type property for all files in my svn repository. What is the most efficient way of doing this in Subversion?

#### WHAT I HAVE TRIED:

I created a file which contains all files in my svn repository (one file per line) named "all-files.txt" and I can use that as input to a bash while loop, but this is not very efficient. The code I used is shown below for completeness:

```
while read ff; do

    MIME_TYPE=`svn propget svn:mime-type svn://myrepository/$ff`

    echo $MIME_TYPE $ff

done < all-files.txt
```

The above works, but it is slow... I tried a similar loop in Perforce and the performance was similar, but Perforce allows me to use the "/..." syntax to operate on all files as shown below, and I am hoping that Subversion has something similar.

#### COMPARISON:

By comparison, this is what I have done in Perforce:

```
p4 files //depot/...
```

Using the "/..." notation I tell Perforce to operate on all files under the directory specified, and the result is orders of magnitude faster. I calculated it would have taken more than 38 hours using a loop, but using the "/..." syntax I got all the answer for all files in a matter of minutes.

I read the "glob" section on the Subversion manual but did not see a similar way of specifying "all-files". What is the most efficient way of operating on all files in a Subversion repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most *svn* commands support the options `-R` and `--depth` for recursive (and non-recursive) operations. It also works with *propget* and looks as follows:

```
svn propget -R svn:mime-type https://example.org/svn/foobar
```

If you execute the command from a working directory, you can use a shortcut for the URL:

```
svn propget -R svn:mime-type ^/
```

The above commands provide the information as text. This might cause problems, if file names or properties contain special characters. If you use this command for some kind of automation, I recommend using the option `--xml` and parse the XML document.

```
svn propget -R svn:mime-type --xml ^/
```

Comment: Thank you! I was reading the wrong section of the manual! I was reading about "File Patterns in Subversion" and "globs" ?, *, etc. but the answer was in "svn help propget" :-) Your answer was very valuable, and I like the trick of using the --xml option.

Comment: The only thing that I would add to your answer is that, depending on the size of the repository, using -R may not give immediate feedback to the user. My repository has millions of files, and when I issued the propget command against my repository (with the -R flag), the command took 4 hours to complete, all the time without any feedback... I thought I had crashed my server ;-) But eventually the command returned and the output was as expected. Thaks again.

Comment: @capnwhit: Which version of _subversion_ are you using on the server, and which repository format in which version? 4 hours is a lot. I would expect, that a recent version of _subversion_ is a lot faster than that. http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#fsfs-enhancements